# how to use a variable in vim search string

Tags: vim

I've got a long vim regex which I use often and in this regex, there is an id which repeats several times. What I want to achieve is to keep this id parametric in the search string so by setting different values to the id, I can run the search and get different matches as required.

For example, if the search regex is below;

`/input\(1\|output\(1\|mux\(1`

I want to parametrise 1 so I can temper with it like `:let res_id=1` etc.

Can I do it with regular '/' search or do I need vim scripting? I really am not a vim junkie, so, sorry for the format of the question.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you cannot `set var=value`, you might mean `let`? you cannot put variable in `/` search. while with vim script you can.

Comment: @Kent yep, I meant let, sorry. it's a shame but hey ho, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `/` search, you cannot use variable. What you can try is, set the `/` register.

For example,

```
function! MySearch(myVar)
    let @/='input\('.a:myVar.'\|output\('.a:myVar.'\|mux\('.a:myVar
endfunction
```

then you pass `newValue` by `:call MySearch('newValue')`

Comment: Looks so simple when you know the answer, doesn't it :) That does the job, thanks very much.